# How do I change $\csc x+\cot x$ into $\frac1{\csc x-\cot x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have the trigonometric expression:
$$\csc x+\cot x$$
And I have to manipulate it into:
$$\frac1{\csc x-\cot x}$$
I've tried, of course, changing the $\csc$ and $\cot$ into $\frac1\sin$ and $\frac1\tan$, but it's gotten me nowhere. I suspect I have to multiply it by some expression over itself but I'm not sure what or how.

Comment: $$\csc^2x-\cot^2x=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the difference of two squares: $$(\csc x+\cot x)(\csc x-\cot x)=\csc^2x-\cot^2x=\frac1{\sin^2x}-\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}=\frac{\sin^2x}{\sin^2x}=1$$ so indeed, $$\boxed{\csc x+\cot x=\frac1{\csc x-\cot x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Show backward:
$$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{\tan x}}=\frac{\sin x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{\sin x(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{1}{\sin x}+\frac{1}{\tan x}$$